# How does the vcard_name attribute work re: input fields?

Tags: html, input, vcf-vcard

Can anyone explain how the (IE) `vcard_name` attribute works as applied to HTML input fields (see below)?

`<input name="foo" vcard_name="bar">`

I've read Microsoft's documentation but am still unclear. In the example above, does the inclusion of the `vcard_name` attribute mean that AutoComplete suggestions will be drawn *exclusively* from the Profile Assistant? Or will suggestions be drawn from both the Profile Assistant *and* the standard autocompletion store?

Also, does the inclusion of the `vcard_name` attribute mean that the user's input will be saved in the Profile Assistant when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.
Thanks

**How It Works (Basically)**

When you enter information into a form and submit it, Internet Explorer sets up what's known as a vCard. The reason the function is so successful is that Web authors tend to use the same NAME attributes for many form elements across pages.

For instance, I'll bet you've filled out a ton of forms that ask for your name. Allow me to demonstrate. Type the first few letters of your name in the text box just below. If you're using IE 5.0 or above, I'll bet your name appears as a choice you can make. Try it in the e-mail box, too. I'll bet you get your e-mail as a choice. It won't work for everyone, but I'll bet I get the majority of you:

If it worked for you, and I'll bet it did, you're probably wondering how I knew each item would come up. Well, first off, here's the code from the form above:

```
<FORM>
Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name">
E-mail: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email">
</FORM>
```

It's the NAME attribute that does the trick. I'm basically making a guess that sometime, somewhere, you filled out a form that asked for your name and e-mail address. In addition, I am guessing that the form used the NAME attributes "name" and "email". They are very common.

If it worked, then you have a couple of vCards on your system named "VCARD_NAME" and "VCARD_EMAIL". When you filled out the other form and submitted it, the card was created. Now, from that point on, whenever you run into a form that has an element with a NAME attribute set to "name" or "email," the text from that vCard will be suggested to you.

Let me attempt to prove that point again. Below is a form that looks exactly like the one above, except the first text box has its NAME attribute set to "griswald" and the second set to "ookook". Go ahead, try to put your name and email in. You'll get no help from AutoComplete.

You didn't get any help because you don't have VCARD_GRISWALD or VCARD_OOKOOK on your computer. Luckily, I didn't give you the opportunity to submit the form, or you would have.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful - although it doesn't describe use of the `vcard_name` attribute itself (only the `name` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the *vcard_name* attribute **overrides** the *name* attribute. It tells the browser to use the vcard_name value passed as the schema to look for AutoComplete suggestions. If this is not provided, the *name* attribute is used.

> Specifies the vCard type to use for the Autocomplete box. Setting the
>   value of the vCard_name attribute causes the contents of the
>   Autocomplete window to depend on the value of this attribute only,
>   **regardless of the value of the name attribute**. If the value of the
>   vCard_name attribute is not specified, the contents of the
>   Autocomplete window depend on the value of the name attribute.
>   Source : http://help.dottoro.com/lhwgvcmt.php